# Why doesn't __declspec(dllimport) work with memcpy() in Visual C++? How do I make it work?

Tags: c, optimization, visual-c++, dllimport

I've noticed that `__declspec(dllimport)` doesn't work with `memcpy` in Visual C++.
i.e., the linker [introduces a `jmp` thunk](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xef53Md8r), regardless of the `dllimport`, so that instead of

```
    call    QWORD PTR __imp_memcpy
```

I get

```
    call    memcpy
```

What's the reason for this behavior? How do I remove the jump overhead for `memcpy`?

Comment: `#pragma function(memcpy)` fixes it in the optimized Release build.  But does kill optimization options, so keep it isolated in the translation unit you care about.

Comment: @HansPassant: Are you sure? [It doesn't work for me](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/W1881v6PP). Also, do you know of any way to get `dllimport` without killing the optimizations? I've been trying everything I can think of (even inline assembly, `.def` files, messing with the object file symbols, etc.) and failing—it seems not just the compiler but also the *linker* refuses to import `memcpy` as `__imp_memcpy` like it would with any other function.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to occur when the translation unit contains a function declaration that is **not** `dllimport`ed.
However, **that includes *implicit* declarations by the compiler under `/Oi`** (which is implied by `/O2`).

Therefore, avoiding this problem requires doing two things:

1. Modifying *all* declarations of `memcpy` to be `__declspec(dllimport)`.
   (This might require macro hackery via `#define memcpy bad_memcpy` or such.)
2. Compiling with `/Oi-` to prevent the internal declaration from being introduced.

Unfortunately, this is an unsatisfactory workaround as it appears to inhibit compiler optimizations for `memset`... and I don't know of any way to work around that simultaneously.
Does anyone else know how to avoid that problem as well?

Also note that disabling intrinsics in the project properties in the IDE may **not** be sufficient, as Visual C++ doesn't necessarily emit `/Oi-` as a result of that if it thinks the option was already disabled. (That also seems like a bug.)

And indeed, [we see the issue is fixed when we do this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PbTdxE7rW):

```
   call    QWORD PTR __imp_memcpy
```

I would think this is a bug though... the internal declaration by the compiler shouldn't override the user-specified one.